# Clang memory allocation

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

Could anyone please help me understand why Clang reallocates the same memory address for different variables while their lifetimes intersect?

I am using a sample program (below) to show the problem.

When I compile the program with clang -O0, variable `j` in function `ok` has the same memory address as variable `solutions` in function `nqueens`.

Function `ok` is called inside function `nqueens`, which means that the lifetime of the variables intersect; the same stack space cannot be used/reused for both functions.

Compiling the program with `gcc` or `clang` at `-O1`, however, they are assigned different memory addresses.

Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <alloca.h>

/* Checking information */

static int solutions[] = {
  1,
  0,
  0,
  2,
  10, /* 5 */
  4,
  40,
  92,
  352,
  724, /* 10 */
  2680,
  14200,
  73712,
  365596,
};
#define MAX_SOLUTIONS sizeof(solutions)/sizeof(int)

int total_count;
int sharedVar = 0;

int ok(int n, char *a)
{
  int i, j;
  char p, q;
  printf("jjjjjjjjj: %d, %p\n", n,&j);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p = a[i];


    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      q = a[j];
      if (q == p || q == p - (j - i) || q == p + (j - i))
    return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

void nqueens (int n, int j, char *a, int *solutions)
{
  int i,res;
  sharedVar = sharedVar * j - n;
  if (n == j) {
    /* good solution, count it */
    *solutions = 1;
    return;
  }
  printf("solutions: %d, %p\n", j, &solutions);
  *solutions = 0;

  /* try each possible position for queen <j> */
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[j] = (char) i;
    if (ok(j + 1, a)) {
      nqueens(n, j + 1, a,&res);
      *solutions += res;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int size = 3;
  char *a;
  // printf("total_count: %p\n", &total_count);
  total_count=0;
  a = (char *)alloca(size * sizeof(char));
  printf("Computing N-Queens algorithm (n=%d) ", size);
  sharedVar = -5;
  nqueens(size, 0, a, &total_count);
  printf("completed!\n");
  printf("sharedVar: %d\n", sharedVar);
}
```

Comment: Their lifetimes don't intersect.

Comment: What were the addresses?